# How to pass videoID on to external file

Tags: javascript

I use 'video.js' as an external JavaScript file. As you can see the `videoID` has to be given in this file. But I would like to pass this value on from my HTML file, so I don't need the include all the JavaScript inside my HTML.

**JavaScript (saved as video.js)**:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('playVid', {
    videoId: 'HERE COMES THE VIDEO ID', // YouTube Video ID
    width: 640,               // Player width (in px)
    height: 360,              // Player height (in px)
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
      loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 1,  // Hide the Video Annotations
      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="playVid"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works perfect, but again my question:

How can I incorporate the `videoID` in my HTML, while the rest of the (JavaScript)code stays in the external JavaScript file (video.js).

Comment: It really depends on how you want to incorporate the `videoID` in your _html_. if you just want to include the `videoID` like a JavaScript variable, then both of the answers 'Tony Sejas', 'Hayden' till now will do the job. but let's say you have a link and you want to show the video when clicking on that link, then you have to take slightly the same approach as these two answers, but edit them to meet your desire

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playVid"></div>
<script>
    var youtubVideoId = 'YOUR_VIDEO_ID';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pretty sure that would do it. Then just reference the JS variable inside the `video.js` file.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('playVid', {
    videoId: youtubVideoId, // YouTube Video ID
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a javascript var in your html. And in your .js file you just use that var you created.
Like this:

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('playVid', {
    videoId: myVideoIdVar, // YouTube Video ID
    width: 640,               // Player width (in px)
    height: 360,              // Player height (in px)
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
      loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 1,  // Hide the Video Annotations
      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myVideoIdVar = 'HERE COMES THE VIDEO ID'
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playVid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```